# Android Jsoup find specific element

Tags: android, jsoup

I wish to parse IMBD page to get the movie rating. (Please do not offer me APIs). This is my code (for now):

```
private static class getData extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void>
{

    String url = "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0437086/";


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {

        try {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements img = document.select("span");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I get all the span, but do I need to cycle all of them to find the rating?
What I need is the rating from this line (specifically the rating itself):

```
<span itemprop="ratingValue">7.5</span>
```

How can I get the rating without cycling trough all elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select a specific `span`

```
Elements img = document.select("span[itemprop=ratingValue]");
Log.e("TEST", "Result: " + img.text());
```

I tested here and it is properly printing `7.5`

You can find more info about the selector syntax [here](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)